# Find the minimum and maximum value of $\frac{1}{\sin{x} -3\cos{x} +5}$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the maximum value and minimum value of
$$\frac{1}{\sin{x} -3\cos{x} +5}.$$ Any tips?

Comment: The derivative is rather elementary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice the following:

$\sin{x} -3\cos{x}$

$=\sqrt{10}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\sin{x} - \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\cos{x})$

$=\sqrt{10}(\cos{\alpha}\sin{x} +\sin{\alpha}\cos{x})$; (where $\tan{\alpha} = -3)$

$=\sqrt{10}\sin{(x+\alpha)}$

Now, since the 'sine' function lies between -1 and 1, the expression "$\sin{x} -3\cos{x}$" lies between $-\sqrt{10}$ and $\sqrt{10}$. Put these values for the epression in your overall expression to find it's range.

Comment: Just to verify: the min. value will be $\dfrac{1}{5+\sqrt{10}}$ and the max. value will be $\dfrac{1}{5-\sqrt{10}}$

Comment: To expand upon this answer the minimum will be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}+5}=\frac{5-\sqrt{10}}{15}$ and the maximum will be $\frac{1}{5-\sqrt{10}}=\frac{5+\sqrt{10}}{15}$

Comment: Technically, you're implicitly using the fact that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+5}$ is monotonic over the domain $[-\sqrt{10}, \sqrt{10}]$. Perhaps this cannot simply be assumed, and may need to be proven.

Comment: @Deepak - That's an interesting point indeed! Let's say the original function, in the question, was the one you have written above. Now, clearly that would be monotonic. Why? That's because, if I increase 'x' (i.e. go from left to right on the x-axis), then "x+5" will increase, and therefore 1/(x+5) will decrease monotonically (of course, I shouldn't crossover the point x=-5).

Comment: @Deepak - But in the question, instead of 'x', I have another function, say g(x)=sin(x)-3cos(x). What was asked in the question was the maximum and minimum value of f(x)=1/(g(x)+5), which will clearly be attained at the min. and max. value of g(x), respectively. That is what my claim is. The function g(x) itself may not be monotonic (and therefore, neither will be f(x)), but we can safely comment on the bounds of the function regardless of that. So, there is no need to check the monotonicity. For example, -1<=sinx<=1, even though sin(x) is not monotonic!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the fact....

$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ge a\sin x+b\cos x\ge -\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The expression in the denominator is greater than $1$

Also, the expression $\frac 1 x$ becomes small when $x$ is big, and big when $x$ is small.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

For $f(x)=\dfrac{A\sin x+B\cos x+C}{P\sin x+Q\cos x+R},$

let $f(x)=y$ and use [Weierstrass Substitution](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Weierstrass_Substitution) to form a Quadratic Equation in $\tan\dfrac x2$

As $\tan\dfrac x2$ is real, the discriminant will be $\ge0$

This will give us the extreme possible values of $y=f(x)$

Answer (score -1):

$-\sqrt {10}+5\leq \sin x-3\cos x+5\leq \sqrt {10}+5\\ \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt {10}+5}\leq \frac{1}{\sin x-3\cos x+5}\leq \frac{1}{-\sqrt {10}+5}$